# Sed/Awk: how to insert text in a series pattern in a line

Tags: unix, awk, sed

need to insert '\N' between whereever 2 sequencial commas in the line like below:

```
"abc,,,,5,,,3.2,,"
```

to:

```
"abc,\N,\N,\N,5,\N,\N,3.2,\N,"
```

Also, the number of the consequencial comma is not fixed, maybe 6, 7 or more. Need a flexible way to handle it.

Didn't find a clear solution from the google.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can just use the following `sed` command:

```
sed 's/,,/,\\N,/g;s/,,/,\\N,/g;'
```

**Demo:**

```
$ echo 'abc,,,,5,,,3.2,,' | sed 's/,,/,\\N,/g;s/,,/,\\N,/g;s/,,/,\\N,/g'
abc,\N,\N,\N,5,\N,\N,3.2,\N,
```

**Explanations:**

`s/,,/,\\N,/g` will replace `,,` by `,\N,` globally on the string, you will have however to do two passes on the pattern space to be sure that all the replacements took place giving the commands: `s/,,/,\\N,/g;s/,,/,\\N,/g;`.

**Additional notes:**

To answer to your doubts about this approach not being flexible, I have prepared the following input file.

```
$ cat input_comma.txt 
abc,,,,5,,,3.2,,
,,,,,,def,
1,,,,,,1.2
6commas,,,,,,
7commas,,,,,,,
```

As you can see, it does not matter how many successive commas are present in the input:

```
$ sed 's/,,/,\\N,/g;s/,,/,\\N,/g;s/,,/,\\N,/g' input_comma.txt 
abc,\N,\N,\N,5,\N,\N,3.2,\N,
,\N,\N,\N,\N,\N,def,
1,\N,\N,\N,\N,\N,1.2
6commas,\N,\N,\N,\N,\N,
7commas,\N,\N,\N,\N,\N,\N,
```

With `awk` a similar approach in 2 passes can be implemented in the same way:

```
$ echo "test,,,mmm,,,,aa,," | awk '{gsub(/\,\,/,",\\N,");gsub(/\,\,/,",\\N,")} 1'
test,\N,\N,mmm,\N,\N,\N,aa,\N,
```

Comment: thank for your quick reply.

The issue is that the number of sequencial comma is not just 3 or 4, maybe more.Is there a more flexible way to accomodate it?

Updated my question more clearly.

Comment: @sleepy: The current approach is flexible, there can be as many successive commas in the input file. They will be properly processed!!!

Comment: @sleepy: have you check the flexibility of this `sed` command? I have also added an `awk` command

Comment: just tried it and you're correct. Thanks for the additional explanation.

Answer (score 4):

Could you please try following once.

```
awk '{gsub(/\,\,/,",\\N,");gsub(/\,\,/,",\\N,")} 1' Input_file
```

Comment: Seems some comma is removed. please check the output as below:

$ echo "test,,,mmm,,,,aa,," | awk '{gsub(/\,\,/,",\\N,");gsub(/\,\,/,",")} 1'
OUTPUT: test,\N,mmm,\N,\N,aa,\N,

Comment: Sleepy is right, you should maybe try: `$ echo "test,,,mmm,,,,aa,," | awk '{gsub(/\,\,/,",\\N,");gsub(/\,\,/,",\\N,")} 1'` output: `test,\N,\N,mmm,\N,\N,\N,aa,\N,`

Comment: @Allan, thanks Allan, I have changed it now, thanks buddy for letting know.

Comment: @RavinderSingh13: nice answer as usual buddy! +1 ;-) ;-)

Answer (score 2):

With `perl`:

```
perl -pe '1 while s/,,/,\\N,/g'
```